# How to get the signature of X509 certificate in C#

Tags: c#, x509certificate, signature

I have this x509 demo certificate and need to know the signature:

`-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE----- MIID9jCCA5ugAwIBAgITbwAAeCy9aKcLA99HrAABAAB4LDAKBggqhkjOPQQDAjBj MRUwEwYKCZImiZPyLGQBGRYFbG9jYWwxEzARBgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgNnb3YxFzAV BgoJkiaJk/IsZAEZFgdleHRnYXp0MRwwGgYDVQQDExNUU1pFSU5WT0lDRS1TdWJD QS0xMB4XDTIyMDQxOTIwNDkwOVoXDTI0MDQxODIwNDkwOVowWTELMAkGA1UEBhMC U0ExEzARBgNVBAoTCjMxMjM0NTY3ODkxDDAKBgNVBAsTA1RTVDEnMCUGA1UEAxMe VFNULS05NzA1NjAwNDAtMzEyMzQ1Njc4OTAwMDAzMFYwEAYHKoZIzj0CAQYFK4EE AAoDQgAEYYMMoOaFYAhMO/steotfZyavr6p11SSlwsK9azmsLY7b1b+FLhqMArhB 2dqHKboxqKNfvkKDePhpqjui5hcn0aOCAjkwggI1MIGaBgNVHREEgZIwgY+kgYww gYkxOzA5BgNVBAQMMjEtVFNUfDItVFNUfDMtNDdmMTZjMjYtODA2Yi00ZTE1LWIy NjktN2E4MDM4ODRiZTljMR8wHQYKCZImiZPyLGQBAQwPMzEyMzQ1Njc4OTAwMDAz MQ0wCwYDVQQMDAQxMTAwMQwwCgYDVQQaDANUU1QxDDAKBgNVBA8MA1RTVDAdBgNV HQ4EFgQUO5ZiU7NakU3eejVa3I2S1B2sDwkwHwYDVR0jBBgwFoAUdmCM+wagrGdX NZ3PmqynK5k1tS8wTgYDVR0fBEcwRTBDoEGgP4Y9aHR0cDovL3RzdGNybC56YXRj YS5nb3Yuc2EvQ2VydEVucm9sbC9UU1pFSU5WT0lDRS1TdWJDQS0xLmNybDCBrQYI KwYBBQUHAQEEgaAwgZ0wbgYIKwYBBQUHMAGGYmh0dHA6Ly90c3RjcmwuemF0Y2Eu Z292LnNhL0NlcnRFbnJvbGwvVFNaRWludm9pY2VTQ0ExLmV4dGdhenQuZ292Lmxv Y2FsX1RTWkVJTlZPSUNFLVN1YkNBLTEoMSkuY3J0MCsGCCsGAQUFBzABhh9odHRw Oi8vdHN0Y3JsLnphdGNhLmdvdi5zYS9vY3NwMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIHgDAdBgNV HSUEFjAUBggrBgEFBQcDAgYIKwYBBQUHAwMwJwYJKwYBBAGCNxUKBBowGDAKBggr BgEFBQcDAjAKBggrBgEFBQcDAzAKBggqhkjOPQQDAgNJADBGAiEA7mHT6yg85jtQ GWp3M7tPT7Jk2+zsvVHGs3bU5Z7YE68CIQD60ebQamYjYvdebnFjNfx4X4dop7Ls EBFCNSsLY0IFaQ== -----END CERTIFICATE-----`

How can I get the signature from this certificate?

I used this code :

```
using System;
using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
using bcrypto = Org.BouncyCastle.X509;

namespace signaturex509
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var cert = new X509Certificate2("d:\\cert.pem");
            var certParser = new bcrypto.X509CertificateParser();
            var privateCertBouncy = certParser.ReadCertificate(cert.GetRawCertData());
            var xx = privateCertBouncy.GetSignature();
            Array.Reverse(xx);
            //Signature
            string sign = BitConverter.ToString(xx);

            Console.WriteLine(sign);

            //algorithm
            Console.WriteLine(privateCertBouncy.SigAlgName);
            Console.ReadLine();

        }
    }
}
```

and I got this output `69-05-42-63-0B-2B-35-42-11-10-EC-B2-A7-68-87-5F-78-FC-35-63-71-6E-5E-F7-62-23-66-6A-D0-E6-D1-FA-00-21-02-AF-13-D8-9E-E5-D4-76-B3-C6-51-BD-EC-EC-DB-64-B2-4F-4F-BB-33-77-6A-19-50-3B-E6-3C-28-EB-D3-61-EE-00-21-02-46-30`

and I need this output `H0F!�a(<;Pjw3OOdQƳv!�jf#b^nqc5x_hB5+cBi`

Comment: what is your target goal?

Comment: @Crypt32 I edited the question, I get the signature but not same output I need it

Comment: @Charlieface yes i tried it but it gives me different output. I edited there

Answer (score 1):

> I got this output 69-05-42-63-0B-2B-35-42-11-10-EC-B2-A7-68-87-5F-78-FC-35-63-71-6E-5E-F7-62-23-66-6A-D0-E6-D1-FA-00-21-02-AF-13-D8-9E-E5-D4-76-B3-C6-51-BD-EC-EC-DB-64-B2-4F-4F-BB-33-77-6A-19-50-3B-E6-3C-28-EB-D3-61-EE-00-21-02-46-30
>
> and I need this output H0F!�a(<;Pjw3OOdQƳv!�jf#b^nqc5x_hB5+cBi

https://www.asciitable.com/

- 0x30 is `0`
- 0x46 is `F`
- 0x02 is a control character
- 0x21 is `!`

So it looks like you just want

- Don't reverse the signature
- Send it through Encoding.ASCII.GetString, even though it's gibberish.
- Maybe prepend it with `H` for no apparent reason (perhaps some control codes did weird things?)